"Test framework quit unexpectedly" when running Pytest in PyCharm
I'm running PyCharm Professional 2023.3.4 on an Ubuntu 22.04 machine.
My PyTests run OK from the command line, and from the terminal within PyCharm. But running them directly from PyCharm itself gives the message "Test framework quit unexpectedly", with the error output shown below (in two screenshots).


None of the lines mentioned in the error output reference any of my code.
Here is how the tests are configured:

Can anyone tell me why Pytest is exiting when run from Pycharm, and how to fix the problem?
Thank you in advance for any help.
